How to identify if provided string is a bash or python script
I have been given a strange request: "Create a python program that will  identify if a provided string contains bash or python code".
How can I do this? Are there any python libraries that can help me parse the string and find out if it contains (valid) bash/python code?

Have a parser check its validity. Shellcheck could be one for a shell script.

Since you're already running Python, import ast; ast.parse(script_text) would be a simple way to see if your string is valid python

From an API perspective, best would be for the client to be required to tell you what kind of script it is, instead of expecting you to figure it out.  That has the additional advantage that if you ever want to extend this (somewhat dubious) idea to cover more languages (perl, csh, ruby, ...) then that will be relatively straightforward.

@JohnBollinger , I totally agree with your point of veiw, but sadly, I don't have any power other the api. :(

Time to push back, then.  At minimum, it's not unreasonable to insist that the input carry an appropriate marking identifying the language.  A shebang line would be a natural choice for that.

Extending @JohnBollinger's point, I'd argue that a shebang line is a necessary part of a valid shell script, so anything that doesn't have one can be immediately ruled out from being a shell script. (But note that it's entirely possible for a valid Python program to have a shebang line, so you can't just test for presence/absence to determine what something is.)

This is fundamentally IMPOSSIBLE, because it is possible for a script to be valid in multiple languages (a polyglot, in other words).  For example, https://flower.codes/2023/12/30/polyglot-hello-world.html runs in both Python and Bash - as well as C, Julia, and CoffeeScript!

Does this answer your question? python: how to check syntax of python file/script without executing it?

Whatever the original reason for accepting scripts from a service was - it's 2024 - how can you manage the risk of bad actors taking over the service, and feeding you with bad scripts ?

After a search on the web, this is what I came up with:
To check if string contains valid bash:
Linux & Unix:
import sh

bash_code = "your_bash_code_here"

result = sh.bash("-n", bash_code, _ok_code=[0])

if result.exit_code == 0:
    pass
else:
    pass

Windows:
import subprocess

bash_code = "your_bash_code_here"

result = subprocess.run(["pylint", "--errors-only", "-", bash_code], capture_output=True, text=True)

if result.returncode == 0:
    print("The string contains valid Bash code.")
else:
    print("The string contains invalid Bash code.")

To check if a string contains valid python:
import ast

python_code = "your_python_code_here"

try:
    ast.parse(python_code)
    pass
except SyntaxError as e:
    pass


How do you distinguish here between a syntactically invalid bash code, and valid bash code, which just returns a non-zero exit code?

import re

def identify_script_type(script_text):
    # Common Python keywords and constructs
    python_keywords = [
        "def ", "import ", "print(", "exec(", "except ", "try:", "lambda ",
        "self.", "class ", "global ", "with ", "yield ", "async ", "await "
    ]
    
    # Common Bash keywords and constructs
    bash_keywords = [
        "#!/bin/bash", "echo ", "function ", "if [[", "fi", "done", "do ",
        "then", "elif", "else", "case ", "esac", "for ", "while ", "in ", "&&",
        "||", "$(", "${", "`", "source ", ". ", "sudo ", "export ", "unset ",
        "trap ", "read ", "exit "
    ]
    
    # Check for common Python keywords
    for keyword in python_keywords:
        if keyword in script_text:
            return "python"
    
    # Check for common Bash keywords
    for keyword in bash_keywords:
        if keyword in script_text:
            return "bash"
    
    # If no specific keywords are found, return unknown
    return "unknown"

# Example usage
script_text_python = """
def run():
    print("Hello, Python!")
"""
script_text_bash = """
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello, Bash!"
"""

print(identify_script_type(script_text_python))  # Output: python
print(identify_script_type(script_text_bash))    # Output: bash


This will not. work. Even though these are patterns that commonly appear in python and bash, they may appear in both. For example, exit() is also sometimes used in python.

This might be fine as a heuristic approach for some well-known inputs, but this is way too flaky to work in general imo. Comments alone kind of ruin this approach.
